# audio data ? I need a typical example

Tags: c++, visual-c++, audio, video, audio-streaming

I have looked into predefined clipboard formats and one inexplicable to me is the Audio Stream binary format, I don't know what to copy so that my clipboard will contain a piece of binary audio data. In C# and managed C++ the clipboard class has this format too. Would you please explain and give me example(s) of this type of data. Also, I wonder why just there is not any video data format. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The CF_WAVE clipboard format is simply a .wav file. If you load a .wav file into memory, then you can copy it to the clipboard using code like this:

```
                DWORD BytesRead;
            void* pFData = GlobalLock(hFData);
            if (ReadFile(hFile,pFData,GetFileSize(hFile,NULL),&BytesRead,NULL) == FALSE)
            {
                ErrCode = E_FILE_READ;
            }
            GlobalUnlock(hFData);
```

...

```
        if (OpenClipboard(NULL))
    {
        EmptyClipboard();
        if (SetClipboardData(CF_WAVE,hFData) == NULL)
        {
            GlobalFree(hFData);
        }
        CloseClipboard();
    }
    else
    {
```

Here, hFile the the WAV file handle.